# Phpunit inserts new lines when Laravel factory is used

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, factory

I have written a testsuite using phpunit. When I run any of these tests, the success dots will appear, each with a couple of newlines in between. I have discovered that this only occurs when a factory is used, but can't find what further causes this. Help is greatly appreciated!

**Example factory (note that there's no `?>` at the end)**

```
<?php
use App\Models\EventParticipant;

$factory->define(App\Models\EventParticipant::class, function () {

    // return
    return [
        'n' => 0,
        'ut' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'del' => 'no'
    ];

});
```

**PHPUnit output for tests that use factories**

```
PHPUnit 5.7.23 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.




.




.




.




.




.                                                              6 / 6 (100%)

Time: 8.7 seconds, Memory: 36.00MB

OK (6 tests, 22 assertions)
```

**PHPUnit output for tests that do not use factories**

```
PHPUnit 5.7.23 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.............................                                     29 / 29 (100%)

Time: 6.32 seconds, Memory: 42.00MB
```

Comment: Try removing space inside the factory definition. To be honest, i haven't come across this issue.

Comment: @RazaMehdi Thank you for responding! I just tried removing all spaces, I even tried putting everything on a single line, but unfortunately that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have any echos/prints etc in the model itself?

Comment: Also, show your test code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved! Six of the 83 factories had a leading empty line in them. Removing those of course also removed the new lines when running tests.